# Android Studio - Firebase returns null when trying to sign facebook or google

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

When I'm trying to sign in into `Firebase` using <kbd>Facebook</kbd> or <kbd>Google</kbd>, my app crashes because its not creating a new user to the `Firebase` using `CreateNewUser()`.

**Logcat:-**

> 05-10 09:11:58.180 16986-16986/com.example.sefi.authenticationproject E/VideoAdapter: onCreateViewHolder() >>
>   05-10 09:11:58.191 16986-16986/com.example.sefi.authenticationproject E/VideoAdapter: onCreateViewHolder() <<
>   05-10 09:11:58.193 16986-16986/com.example.sefi.authenticationproject E/VideoAdapter: onBindViewHolder() >> 0
>   05-10 09:11:58.203 16986-16986/com.example.sefi.authenticationproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.sefi.authenticationproject, PID: 16986
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.sefi.authenticationproject.adapter.VideoAdapter.onBindViewHolder(VideoAdapter.java:114)
>           at com.example.sefi.authenticationproject.adapter.VideoAdapter.onBindViewHolder(VideoAdapter.java:32)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6482)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6515)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5458)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5724)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3410)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3962)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18799)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5952)
>           at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1855)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18799)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5952)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18799)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5952)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18799)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5952)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:822)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18799)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5952)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2634)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2350)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1509)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7051)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:927)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:638)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:913)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)

**LogInActivity.java**

```
public class LogInActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String TAG = "LogInActivity";
    private static final int RC_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN = 1001;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
    private AccessTokenTracker mAccessTokenTracker;
    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;

    private EditText mEmail;
    private EditText mPass;
    private TextView mStatus;
    private boolean mIsSignup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.log_in_activity);

        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.email_id);
        mPass = findViewById(R.id.password_id);
        mStatus = findViewById(R.id.status_id);

        firebaseAuthenticationInit();
        googleSigninInit();
        facebookLoginInit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {

        Log.e(TAG, "onStart() >>");

        super.onStart();

        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

        updateLoginStatus("N.A");

        Log.e(TAG, "onStart() <<");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {

        Log.e(TAG, "onStop() >>");

        super.onStop();

        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "onStop() <<");

    }

    public void onEmailPasswordAuthClick(View V) {

        Log.e(TAG, "onEmailPasswordAuthClick() >>");

        String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
        String pass = mPass.getText().toString();

        Task<AuthResult> authResult;
        boolean canContinue = checkIfEmailOrPasswordIsRequired(email, pass);
        if (canContinue == true)
        {
            switch (V.getId()) {
                case R.id.sign_in_id:
                    //Email / Password sign-in
                    authResult = mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
                    moveToNextScreenAfterValidation(authResult);
                    mIsSignup = false;
                    break;
                case R.id.sign_up_id:
                    //Email / Password sign-up
                    authResult = mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
                    mIsSignup = true;
                    moveToNextScreenAfterValidation(authResult);
                    break;
                default:
                    return;
            }
            authResult.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Email/Pass Auth: onComplete() >> " + task.isSuccessful());

                    if (mIsSignup) {
                        createNewUser();
                    }

                    if (!task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this, "User is already in use or there is a temporary problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    updateLoginStatus(task.isSuccessful() ? "N.A" : task.getException().getMessage());

                    Log.e(TAG, "Email/Pass Auth: onComplete() <<");
                }
            });
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "onEmailPasswordAuthClick() <<");
    }

    public void signInAnonymously(View v) {
        mAuth.signInAnonymously()
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInAnonymously:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LogInActivity.this,StandupPlayerMain.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInAnonymously:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this, "Skip sign up failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    public void onForgetPasswordClick(View V)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LogInActivity.this,ForgotMyPassword.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


        Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResult () >>");

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN) {
            //Google Login...
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Log.e(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
                Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this, "Google signing in falied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // ...
            }
        }

        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResult () <<");
    }

    private void facebookLoginInit() {
        Log.e(TAG, "facebookLoginInit() >>");
        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginButton loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
        loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.e(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess () >>" + loginResult);
                Log.e(TAG, "look for me");
                createNewUser();
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
                Log.e(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess () <<");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.e(TAG, "facebook:onCancel() >>");
                updateLoginStatus("Facebook login canceled");
                Log.e(TAG, "facebook:onCancel() <<");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "facebook:onError () >>" + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this, "Facebook log in failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                updateLoginStatus(error.getMessage());
                Log.e(TAG, "facebook:onError <<");
            }
        });

        mAccessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken,AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
                Log.e(TAG, "facebook:inside Token change <<");
                if (currentAccessToken == null)
                {
                    mAuth.signOut();
                    updateLoginStatus("Facebook signuout");
                }
                Log.e(TAG,"onCurrentAccessTokenChanged() >> currentAccessToken="+
                        (currentAccessToken !=null ? currentAccessToken.getToken():"Null") +
                        " ,oldAccessToken=" +
                        (oldAccessToken !=null ? oldAccessToken.getToken():"Null"));
            }
        };
        Log.e(TAG, "facebookLoginInit() <<");
    }

    private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {

        Log.e(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken () >>" + token.getToken());

        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Facebook: onComplete() >> " + task.isSuccessful());
                        if(task.isSuccessful()==true)
                        {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LogInActivity.this,StandupPlayerMain.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        updateLoginStatus(task.isSuccessful() ? "N.A" : task.getException().getMessage());

                        Log.e(TAG, "Facebook: onComplete() <<");
                    }
                });

        Log.e(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken () <<");

    }

    private void firebaseAuthenticationInit() {

        Log.e(TAG, "firebaseAuthenticationInit() >>");
        //Obtain reference to the current authentication
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LogInActivity.this,StandupPlayerMain.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged() >>");

                updateLoginStatus("N.A");

                Log.e(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged() <<");
            }
        };

        Log.e(TAG, "firebaseAuthenticationInit() <<");
    }

    private void googleSigninInit() {

        Log.e(TAG, "googleSigninInit() >>" );

        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions
                .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestProfile()
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        findViewById(R.id.google_sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.e(TAG, "look for me" + mAuth.getCurrentUser().toString());
                onGooglesignIn();
            }
        });

        Log.e(TAG, "googleSigninInit() <<" );
    }

    private void onGooglesignIn() {

        Log.e(TAG, "onGooglesignIn() >>" );
        createNewUser();
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN);

        Log.e(TAG, "onGooglesignIn() <<" );
    }

    private boolean checkIfEmailOrPasswordIsRequired(String email,String password)
    {
        boolean result = true;
        if (email.length() == 0)
        {
            result = false;
            Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this, "Email is missing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (password.length() == 0)
        {
            result = false;
            Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this, "Password is missing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {

        Log.e(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle() >>" + acct.getId());

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        updateLoginStatus(task.isSuccessful() ? "N.A" : task.getException().getMessage());
                        Log.e(TAG, "look for me");
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LogInActivity.this,StandupPlayerMain.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

        Log.e(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle() <<");

    }

    private void moveToNextScreenAfterValidation(Task<AuthResult> authResult)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "emailPasswordVaildation () >>");
        authResult.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                Log.e(TAG, "emailPasswordVaildation outside if");
                if(task.isSuccessful() == true)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "emailPasswordVaildation inside if");
                    //createNewUser();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LogInActivity.this,StandupPlayerMain.class);
                    intent.putExtra("User Info",mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
        Log.e(TAG, "emailPasswordVaildation () <<");
    }

    private void updateLoginStatus(String details) {

        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (user == null) {
            mStatus.setText("SIGNED-OUT \ndetails:" + details);
        } else {
            mStatus.setText("SIGNED-IN\nname:" + user.getDisplayName() +
                    "\nemail:" + user.getEmail() +
                    "\nuid:" + user.getUid() +
                    "\ndetails:" + details);
        }
    }

    private void createNewUser() {

        Log.e(TAG, "createNewUser() >>");

        FirebaseUser fbUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        if (fbUser == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "createNewUser() << Error user is null");
            return;
        }

        Log.e(TAG,userRef.toString());
        userRef.child(fbUser.getUid()).setValue(new User(fbUser.getEmail(),0,null));

        Log.e(TAG, "createNewUser() <<");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at [creating an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this case mostly the minimal part.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in adapter not in current activity, I guess.

Your logs says:-
*Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference at **com.example.sefi.authenticationproject.adapter.VideoAdapter**.onBindViewHolder(VideoAdapter.java:114)*

Your issue is with activity/fragment where you may be using an adapter "VideoAdapter" and there can be some "view" which is not defined.

If still issue persists, Please use Debugger and run code line by line, and provide more detailed and specific issue.

Comment: But since getCurrentUser of firebase returns null a User entity does not created, therefore onBind fails